# How to trigger event in angular application for "Request Desktop Website in iphone safari" or "Desktop Site in Android"?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, angular, responsive-design

I have requiremnt in my angular appliacation that I want to align website If user choose an option in 
Request Desktop Website in iphone safari or Desktop Site in Android

[image]

for that I got solution that Application meta tag viewport scale is changed when user choose thease options. from this 
stackoverflow link provided answers I got idea that I have to change meta tag scale

[How do I make my responsive website honour "Request a desktop site" on mobiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622686/how-do-i-make-my-responsive-website-honour-request-a-desktop-site-on-mobiles/45640501?noredirect=1#comment105291674_45640501)

Above solution I can do using js or @angular/platform-browser package provided some meta classes

My doubt is How to trigger event in angular application to perform above operations?

Can any one have any idea on thease.

Thanks in advance.